# Is the there a Way to Create a Constructor via Reflection that calls a Base Constructor. Specifically Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-6

I need to be able to call the Entity Framework model constructor of my model in 2 different ways. I either pass a connection string to my class, let's call it `MyDbConnection`, or I pass an existing `EntityConnection` (`DBConnection`) to my context, which comes from another application.

Everything is fine and works so far.

The problem I have, is: every time I want to use this custom way of opening my context in a new project, I need to define the 2 constructors in `MyDbConnection` which is quite a hassle.

Like this:

```
public partial class MyEntityConnection : DbContext
{
    public MyEntityConnection(string con) : base(con)
    {
    }

    public MyEntityConnection(DbConnection con, bool contextOwnsConnection) : base(con, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in my own implementation I do something like this (for the string overload):

```
public T GetDbContext() => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), _connectionstring);
```

and here is the problem. If I forgot to create one or both constructors, this would throw an exception.

Now I do know that you can modify the EF template to autogenerate those constructors, but im Looking for a Hands-Off Way to Archive this.

Some Way to Create the Instance of my Derived Class with a Constructor, that does not exist, and that Construtor should call its Base Constructor.

If there is a better Way to Archive this, I'm all ears.

```
private T GetExistingDbContext()
{
    try
    {
        EntityConnection econ = new EntityConnection(_internalMetadataWorkspace, _internalExistingSqlConnection);
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), econ, false);
    }
    catch (MissingMethodException)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception catr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(catr);
        throw;
    }          
}
```

To Clarify:

I need to Create a Lot of Entity-Contexts

ContextForDataBase1,ContextForDataBase2,ContextForDataBase3 and so on.

My Wrapper works like this:

```
using(var context = new EntityDbConnection<ContextForDataBase1>(_connectionstring)){}
```

the whole point of this is: I dont want to Create Overloads in the Partial Implementation of the Context Classes for my Constructors. I want to Automate that Process somehow.(Modifying the EF Template is not an option)

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're using reflection.   Why can't you call the appropriate constructor as needed?  Constructors can be overloaded.  I must be missing something.

Comment: If the constructor isn't there you can't "create" it by reflection. You can only use reflection to check if the required ctor is present.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes i could call the Constructor of my Entity Class "MyEntityConnection". But that Constructor needs to Exist. So everytime i use my Wrapper to Create a Generic Entity Connection i would need to make sure the Constructor exists in that Entity Conneciton. Usually that is no the Problem, but the Work i do requires Lots of different Databases eg ContextForDB1, ContextForDB2,ContextForDb3 and so on. Meaning Lots of Switching Entity Connection. So I Would like to Automate the Creating or Calling of the Overload somehow.

Answer (score -1):

The constructors needs to be there, with reflection you can only create the type as it is.

Your question is not crystal clear, so from what I understand of it:

you have multiple dbcontexts in different apps and you have a main app (lets call it M for simplicity)

you are saying that you somehow pass the types of dbContexts into M and you want to create new instances of these types of dbcontexts in M however if any of these contexts does not have these constructors it would throw an exception right? if this is your case,
what I would do would be :

1- Create a new class library project. Install EF

2- Create a custom DBContext that inherits from DbContext

3- Add constructors etc.

4- build the project into a .dll file

5- reference the .dll to all projects

6- make your multiple contexts inherit from the custom context

this way you won't have to worry if the constructor is there as long as your contexts inherit from the custom dbcontext

Comment: No. Constructors aren't inherited automatically from base types to inherited types.